# How to use RED.events in node-red to alter editor behavior

Tags: javascript, events, node-red

in our Node-Red deployment scenario we would like to change the behavior of the editor independently from the installed Node Palettes. An example here would be to execute code once the flow has been deployed. The editor API provides the event "deploy" for this, so it is possible to subscribe to exactly this event.

```
RED.events.on("deploy", function() {
    console.log("Deployed!")
})
```

Unfortunately, we don't really know where to put this code. As mentioned before, the general editor behavior should be changed. A plugin for the editor would probably be the right thing, but unfortunately we can hardly find any resources for this. Can you help us to get on the right track?

Should there be a plugin system, is there a tutorial or other resources somewhere that not only describe the API but also show how to apply it properly? The docs are just not enough to helps us here, tbh. Maybe it's also related to the fact that we have little expertise with Node-Red and Javascript development projects in general so far.

Are there possibly public repositories that show similar behavior that we can look at?

Thanks in advance, have a great day.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the right place for this sort of question, it's far too broad. I suggest you ask on the Node-RED discourse forum or Node-RED Slack where a proper discussion can be had. Also Pull Requests to improve the docs will always be well received.

Comment: Thanks @hardillb for your comment. I already posted to the slack channel yesterday under "creating-nodes" and hope to get some helpful feedback there. Nevertheless the audience is much bigger here and unless I am not breaking the rules, I just hope to find someone who can help.

Comment: It is off topic to ask for links to documentation/examples on Stack Overflow and this is the sort of question that can only be solved by a discussion of your project. For this question the audience you want is in the forum/slack not here.